# jssc SerialPort - my software stops running when readbytes

Tags: java, jssc

I'm reading Wiegand card code by a module throught a USB port. I added an event listener to my, it runs perfectly when I pass my card, but after reading the data my software stops running and get stuck, but if pass my card again, the event runs again and get stuck again.

Here is the eventlistener:

```
        serialPort.addEventListener(event -> {
            if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    try {
                        String caractere;
                        do {
                            caractere = new String(serialPort.readBytes(1));
                        }while(!caractere.equals("#"));
                        String str = new String(serialPort.readBytes(16));
                        System.out.println(str);
                        cartaoIdListener.set(str);
                    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error in receiving string from COM-port: " + ex);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
```

These are the settings:

```
        serialPort.openPort();

        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN |
                                        SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
```

Comment: If it gets "stuck" but continues when you feed in more data, then clearly your code is trying to read more data than is available.  Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see what is actually happening?  If not, that is the next step to take.